# How to search record from table and display in gridview in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to .net, I have been created text box,drop down list and searc button.

When i select "starts with" in the drop down and type some characters in the text box and click search button, It should display records(according to search text) from table in gridview.

For that I created drop down, and create stored procedure.And i added following code:

Here is aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<td><asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenfield" runat="server" /> 
<td><asp:HiddenField ID="curricular" runat="server" /> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchid" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
   <td>

    <asp:Label ID="condition" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="searchtext" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </td>    
<asp:DropDownList ID="searchrecord" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="textsearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="searchclick" runat="server" text = "search" OnClick="searchrecords_Click" OnClientClick="return searchrecords();" />
   <center><div><h4>Searched Records</h4></div></center><br /> <br />
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="240px" 
        Width="755px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" 
                SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobilenum" HeaderText="Mobile Number" 
                SortExpression="Mobile Number" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image" ControlStyle-Width="50" ControlStyle-Height = "50">                
                <ControlStyle Height="50px" Width="50px"></ControlStyle>
                </asp:ImageField> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Extracurricular" HeaderText="Extracurricular" 
                SortExpression="Name" />            
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF0066" BorderColor="#CCFFFF" ForeColor="White" 
            Height="50px" Width="50px" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF66FF" />
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="sp_searchedstudentrecords"          
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function searchrecords() {
            if ($.trim(document.getElementById("<%=textsearch.ClientID%>").value).length == 0) {
                alert("Enter Your Characters to search !");
                document.getElementById("<%=textsearch.ClientID%>").focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" />

</asp:Content>
```

Here is my code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
                {
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentsearchrecords", con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", searchid.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchrecords", searchrecord.Text.Trim());

                    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(ds);

                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        searchrecord.DataSource = ds;
                        searchrecord.DataTextField = "searchrecords";
                        searchrecord.DataValueField = "id";
                        searchrecord.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void searchrecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_insertsearchtext", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchname", searchtext.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString();
        }
```

And finally stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_searchedstudentrecords
(
@condition varchar(20),
@searchtext varchar(50)
)
AS
begin
If (@condition = 'startswith')
select * from student where name like @searchtext+ '% '
else if (@condition = 'endswith')
select * from student where name like '%' +@searchtext
else
select * from student where name like '%' +@searchtext+ '%'
End
```

When i run this code, it shows following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.searchrecords_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_RowCommand' and no extension method 'GridView1_RowCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.searchrecords_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm struggling to fix this problem, May i know, how to pass these two `@condition` and `@searchtext` parameters in my code?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

**update:**

```
protected void searchrecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_insertsearchtext", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idsearch.Text.Trim()); 
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchtext", searchtext.Text.Trim());               
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString();
        }
```

and

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_insertsearchtext
    (
    @id int,
@searchtext Varchar (100)
)
AS
begin
Insert into searchtext (searchtext) values (@searchtext)
End
```

Comment: Remove the OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" from ASPX. Or add relevant  event to code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your code first is you have registered the *RowCommand* event using `OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"` but you have not defined it so either you will have to handle it in code behind or else remove the attribute from gridview.

Second problem is that you have used a SQLDataSource control to trigger the SP `sp_searchedstudentrecords` and which expects two parameters i.e. `@condition` & `@searchtext` but you are passing none of them from your control. I guess you want to pass these values from your dropdownlist and textbox controls resp. then change your code like this:-

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp_searchedstudentrecords"          
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchrecord" Name="condition" 
             PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchtext" Name="searchtext" PropertyName="Text" 
             Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: i will check with your answer and will update you, thanks

Comment: Now didn't show error.. but didn't display record in gridview after click search button.

Comment: @Rani - Hey `SQLDataSource` control is there to take care of these things I mean calling SP and binding the data. You have done both i.e have SQLDataSource as well as custom code to call SP, either just use `SQLDataSource` control or else just write custom code not both.

Comment: I can't able to understand..:(

Comment: ok.. what i have to add code under searchrecords_Click event? thanks

Comment: ok.. i need to use searchrecords_Click.. for that what i do?.. when i clcik search button.. it should shows record in gridview..can you please help

Answer (score 0):

There is an `OnRowCommand` event declared in your ASPX for `GridView` called `GridView1_RowCommand`. But its not defined in you code behind. Remove the `OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"` event from ASPX. Or add that event to code behind.

Comment: I can't understand.. can you please elaborate ? thanks

Comment: @Rani Answer Updated.

Comment: if i remove OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" ..rest of the lines shows as error.

Comment: Yes. But the issue you specified in the question is because that event.

Comment: Procedure or function 'sp_searchedstudentrecords' expects parameter '@condition', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

At first you wants to change the parameter name in your code behind,
because the parameter name must be same in your query and code behind..

protected void searchrecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_insertsearchtext", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition",idsearch.Text.Trim()); 
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchtext",searchtext.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString();
        }